# MySQL Query Generate Report By Period Of 10 Days

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have a table like this

```
id  | user_id | point | created_at
-------------------------------------------
1   | 1       | 10    | 2015-08-03 00:08:25 
2   | 3       | 20    | 2015-08-01 00:08:25 
3   | 4       | 30    | 2015-08-13 00:08:25 
4   | 3       | 10    | 2015-08-25 00:08:25 
5   | 2       | 20    | 2015-09-02 00:08:25 
6   | 1       | 10    | 2015-09-14 00:08:25 
7   | 4       | 50    | 2015-09-22 00:08:25 
8   | 2       | 80    | 2015-09-30 00:08:25 
9   | 1       | 30    | 2015-10-02 00:08:25 
10  | 5       | 90    | 2015-10-02 00:08:25
```

Can i generate a query to make a result like this?

```
start_date | end_date   | total_point_100_or_more | total_point_less_than_100
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2015-08-01 | 2015-08-10 | 3 User                  | 7 User
2015-08-11 | 2015-08-20 | 8 User                  | 5 User
2015-08-21 | 2015-08-30 | 10 User                 | 5 User
2015-08-31 | 2015-09-09 | 4 User                  | 6 User
```

I don't have any line of code right now as i totally don't have any idea where to start.

Comment: what if the min(created_at) is Aug 4. Does it go in 10 chunks from that? Devil's in the details

Comment: you need to create a stored procedure which will be reading your table and perform your required operations like filtering and summing 10 days data and placing them into one table, then you can read that table as your output, you can schedule this stored procedure on daily basis to update your recent records.

Comment: @Drew, if the start_date is Aug 4 then end_date will be Aug 13.

Comment: @GauravLad, so there's no way i can generate this result only with single query?

Comment: @otezz: if there would be a way then it won't be good to fire same query every time to get data, as it has start date and end date your data won't be changing for month of August when it is month of Sept. so why to calculate for August every time, better we maintain the calculation by running just once using stored procedure. So i feel that using stored procedure will be optimized way.

Comment: @GauravLad: very good point. I think i'll just go with your suggestion.

Comment: @otezz: will try to provide some sample stored procedure, you can improve it as per your requirements. (mean while, you can up-rate my comments as useful)

Comment: You can call DATEDIFF to get the number of days since the start of your 10-day cycle, and integer-divide that by ten (rounding down) before multiplying again by ten and use DATEADD to get back to the start date of the period. Do that in a sub-query and you can GROUP BY that value. So yes, you can do it in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, and can't since your sample answer doesn't correspond to your sample data, but something very like the following should work. Here I'm assuming that you want to know how may users got a total score (during each period) above or below 100.

```
SELECT  start_date,
        DATEADD(day, 9, start_date) as end_date,
        SUM(CASE WHEN period_points >= 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_point_100_or_more,
        SUM(CASE WHEN period_points < 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_point_less_than_100
FROM (
        SELECT  start_date,
                user_id,
                SUM(point) as period_points
        FROM (
                SELECT  DATEADD(
                                day,
                                DATEDIFF(day, '2015-08-01 00:00:00', created_at)/10*10,
                                '2015-08-01 00:00:00'
                        ) as start_date,
                        id,
                        user_id,
                        point
                FROM    points
        ) AS p
        GROUP BY start_date, user_id
) as q
GROUP BY start_date
```

Note that I didn't convert the integer counts to text and append " User" as in your sample.